# rewrite rule request

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

How to set a rewrite rule or PHP code for the following:

A User requests a page like `/samy.john`. But this page does not exist, so he will get redirected to `/index.html` and in the headline of *index.html* there will be a message that says *Hello Samy* which is taken from the first part of the URL he requested.

Any clues how to apply this?

Comment: do you have any more situations in that url? like test.com/index,html? If so, you can create a rule in the htaccess to transform urls that doesn't end with .html for instance.

Comment: its just simple index.html and already ive create htacces rules redirect me to index.html if the page dosnt exist but the 2nd part of my need is show index.html after redirect Hello $name where is name is page requested and not founder like test.com/samy.john after redirect it show in headline of index.html Hello samy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet to accomplish what you described is to have everything direct to an index.php file and then handle the redirecting yourself.

If you had everything fall to the index file you could then check the $_SERVER var for SCRIPT_URL or SCRIPT_URI, whatever meets your needs, and then say if that page didn't exist, but it meets your requirements for first_name.last_name  you could then redirect, or include the content needed, so that the homepage would be displayed with hello first_name displayed.

Hope that helps.